# Create alphabetical NSDictionary from NSArray

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

Let's say I have an array that looks like this:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo", @"Camel", @"Cockatoo", @"Dog", @"Donkey", @"Emu"]
```

How can I create following dictionary out of it?

```
NSDictionary *animals;
animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
            @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
            @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
            @"E" : @[@"Emu"]};
```

Comment: datasource is a array?

Comment: yes datasource is array

Comment: You are creating dictionary right??? Then what do you want else? Because your code seems to be correct.

Comment: i got this sample dictionary. i want to create dictionary like this. i am not creating it

Comment: You have already created , this is perfact dictionary which you have posted in question having keys as "B,C,D etc" and it's value is array.

Comment: what i want is how to create dictionary by passing multiple values to one key.

Comment: Like you have posted in question!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: yes. like have posted in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you are trying to create a dictionary out of an array.

Try this:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo", @"Camel", @"Cockatoo", @"Dog", @"Donkey", @"Emu"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *animal in array) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [animal substringToIndex:1];

    if (!dictionary[firstLetter]) {
        dictionary[firstLetter] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [((NSMutableArray *)dictionary[firstLetter]) addObject:animal];
}
```

At the end the value of dictionary is:

```
dictionary = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
            @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
            @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
            @"E" : @[@"Emu"]};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this by :

`NSMutableDictionary* animals =[NSMutableDictionary new];
 NSArray* wAnimals =@[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"];
[animals setObject:wAnimals forKey:@"W"];`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (Hope this will help you and i think you want like this)-

```
-(NSDictionary*)makeCustomDictionary:(NSString*)yourValue{

    [array addObject:yourValue];

    NSMutableArray *lettersKey = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *string in array) {

        if (string.length > 0) {

            NSString *letter = [string substringToIndex:1];

            if (![lettersKey containsObject:letter]) {

                [lettersKey addObject:letter];

                NSString *stringToSearch = letter;

                NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",stringToSearch]; // if you need case sensitive search avoid '[c]' in the predicate

                NSArray *results = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

                [values addObject:results];

            }
        }
    }


    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:lettersKey];
}
- (IBAction)addNewValue:(id)sender {
    NSDictionary *tempDic=[self makeCustomDictionary:txt.text];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tempDic
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];
    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"dictionary in json form - %@ \n\n or dictionary simple- %@",jsonString,tempDic);
    }

}
```

here **array** is global `NSMutableArray` initialize in `viewDidLoad()`.
Output-

```
 dictionary in json form - 
{
     "D" : ["Dog","Donkey"],
     "B" : ["Bear","Black Swan","Buffalo"],
     "G" : ["Giraffe"],
     "E" : ["Emu"],
     "C" : ["Camel","Cockatoo"]
}

or dictionary simple- {
    B =     (
             Bear,
             "Black Swan",
             Buffalo
             );
    C =     (
             Camel,
             Cockatoo
             );
    D =     (
             Dog,
             Donkey
             );
    E =     (
             Emu
             );
    G =     (
             Giraffe
             );
}
```